# How to add a reactjs router for a landing page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router, service-worker

I need to be able to land on a page to validate the user email and to let them change the password based on a token sent by email, so I tried adding a react router like:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
<Route exact path="/users" component={About} />
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/users/activation" component={About} />
   <Route exact path="/users/recoverpassword" component={About} />
   <Route exact path="/users/activation/:atoken" component={Activation} />
   <Route exact path="/users/recoverpassword/:ptoken" component={PasswordRecovery} />
</Switch>
```

But it only works if I land on initial page website.com/ page first and go to /users than to /users/activation and than to /users/activation/123

If I land straight on /users/activation/123 it shows nginx 404

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

Not sure yet if its related to nginx cache, service-worker.js or to the router it self.

How can I have multiple landing routers?

Comment: Looks like a problem with nginx setup. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx).

Comment: Thanks a lot @FK82, adding this to my default config of nginx solved the issue: 
`location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}`

Answer (score 1):

It should be the issue with nginx cache or configuration. Try modifying it NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
     <BrowserRouter  >
                     <Route push={true} path="/users/activation/:atoken" component={Activation}/> 
      </BrowserRouter>
```