# Docker Reverse Proxy to React App with React Router

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, react-router, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've been hitting my head on the keyboard for 3 days trying to figure out why I can't get this to work.

Right now I am running two nginx servers on my machine. Both are running in docker containers.

One nginx is a reverse proxy. The other nginx is the actual one serving the static files built by 'yarn build'.

I currently get a 404 error when trying to access any of the files out side of the root file.

So example.com works just fine. But when I go to example.com/test (a react route) I get a 404 error.

So, here is my reverse proxy confiruation.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.29:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/html;
    }
}
```

Here is my actual example.com confiration to serve the static files (yes it's port 80 because it's running on port 80 inside the docker container. The exposed docker container port is 8080:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
    }
}
```

Comment: What result do you get if you connect directly to the NGINX machine that is serving the files? Does it work as expected then?

Comment: Same result, 404 error. I should've mentioned that as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx There is solution. I had the same problem.