# How to fix 404 when reloading page in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble with reactjs in production, in my development machine i can easily refresh/reload without redirecting to 404 (not found page) but during production every time i reload or refresh in `http://example.com/subdirectory/dashboard` it will always go to 404 page of `http://example.com` but when I'm in development machine http://localhost:3000/subdirectory/dashboard when I refresh/reload the page it will reload as expected.

Note: In production I uploaded my static data into subdirectory so i use basename in my route.

Comment: I think in production you need to enable rewrite rules.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your serving your application on a standard webserver you can add a `.htaccess` using the following which enables rewrite rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

It's likely that the 404 issue you're facing will be solved by simply just serving the above alongside the root of the project.

Alternately you could use the following as well which would serve it as a node server:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000);
```

The above can be used in conjunction with a `.htaccess`.

The create react app guys also promote serve which you can find [here](https://github.com/zeit/serve) and the official react deployment documentation [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#docsNav)

1: https://github.com/zeit/serve

2: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#docsNav

Comment: Thank you so much you save my day `.htaccess` save my day.

Comment: Also `AllowOverride All` directive in apache config may be needed to enable `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

In your http server you have to rewrite all urls to your index.html file. If you are using `nginx` you can follow this: [React-router and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx)

Answer (score 1):

You might have to create a proxy server for your React.js application in production. You can do this in different ways but to do it with Express Node.js, you would have to create a file that looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const port = 7700;

const app = express();


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

The snippet above assumes you have built your React files and your index.html is in a `public` directory. This proxies all requests from the express server to your React routes with the `*` wildcard.

With that done, all that's left is to run this express app on your server and it handles your history API routes just like regular server routes.

Answer (score 0):

add basename inside your src/index.js like this
(you can also add `<base href="/subdirectory" target="_blank">` in your index.html file's head tag)

```
            <Router
                basename={'/subdirectory'}
            >
                <App />
            </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **public** folder make a file **_redirects**  and write
**/*    /index.html   200** in it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).