# How to always redirect to index.html in Nginx Docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, config

I'm using `nginx:1.16.0-alpine` image of Docker for serve react app (which is built before) and I want to redirect to `index.html` page in any cases (in what URL is got)

`nginx.conf` file has the following content:

```
user  nginx; worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn; pid       
/var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024; }

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location ~ ^/$ {
            rewrite  ^.*$  /index.html  last;
        }
    }
}
```

Actually the `server` section is added and the other lines are default!

`Dockerfile` content is as below as well:

```
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

COPY ./build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

For making sure, after building the container from the image and going to the shell inside that, the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` has the above content.

But the problem is: When I browse the url **http://localhost:3000/login** (for example), it doesn't redirect to **http://localhost:3000/index.html**. It shows:

> 404 Not Found nginx/1.16.0

(Docker container is run on output port 3000 and local port on 80)

Does anybody know why it is not working!?
(I also searched the similar ways, but no success!)

**UPDATED:**
 The page [React-router and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx)  doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @emix, please look at the `location` section which says any URL redirects to `/index.html`, but doesn't work

Comment: Ok the content is hidden in mobile. You have serious formatting issues with your question. It’s a code, not sure why you put it inside a quote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx)

Comment: @yurloc, Unfortunately no!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment the following line

```
# include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Why? Due to the line

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

The default.conf is loaded and your server config is ignored.

In addition, you need to include the root information in your server (which previously was provided by default.conf

---

#### How to reproduce

put the following 2 files in the same folder and execute

```
docker build -t test . && docker run --rm -p 8080:80 test
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

# COPY ./build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user nginx; worker_processes auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn; pid
/var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http { include /etc/nginx/mime.types; default_type application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

#include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/$ {
        rewrite  ^.*$  /index.html  last;
    }
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't work. the error message changed to "500 Internal Server Error - nginx/1.16.0"

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer - including the default server config will surely mess with the server config you have added.  You should do one or the other - more typical would be to add your server config to `conf.d/default.conf`.  In any case, if you are now getting a `500`, you need to check the logs and find out why.

Comment: To avoid `500`, add `root   /usr/share/nginx/html;` under `server` directive (taken from a more advanced configuration: https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/nginx.html).

Comment: @Don'tPanic, This is the log after going to localhost:3000/login: `2020/01/07 11:49:33 [error] 6#6: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:3000"`
`172.17.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2020:11:49:33 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 500 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36" "-"`

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi, I've updated the answer to take the missing root into account

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi, great! I recommend, that you put the server definition into a dedicated file copy it into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` as `default.conf` and leave the original `nginx.conf` as is. e.g. do not copy `nginx.conf` into your container, but `default.conf` into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` containing only the server section. If you need help a hand with that, let me know.