# Nginx: Serving all content from the same directory on the server (even though the URL changes)

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-location

I built a React app and all of the files are served from the same physical directory on my Nginx server.  I use react-router-dom to navigate through the app.  Everything works when I first load the app.

I'll navigate to a URL that react-router-dom knows (like http://example.com/blog/posts/) but when I try to **refresh** the page, Nginx responds with 404 Not Found.  I know this is happening because Nginx is looking for a sub-folder on the server that matches /blog/posts.

I can't figure out how to tell Nginx to serve all content from the same root folder **regardless** of the path in the browser.

So no matter what the path...

```
/blog  
/blog/posts  
/blog/posts/1  
/contact
/summary/page/4   
....
```

... all files are served from the same `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my.domain.com/html/index.html` file on the server (which is the root page of the app)

All of these versions don't work when I **refresh** the page:

```
location / {
     alias /etc/nginx/sites-available/my.domain.com/html;
     index index.html;
 }
```

```
location / {
     root /etc/nginx/sites-available/my.domain.com/html;
     index index.html;
 }
```

```
location ~ ^/ {
     root /etc/nginx/sites-available/my.domain.com/html;
     index index.html;
 }
```

Comment: duplicate of [React-router and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43954597/1067109

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```