# Deploy ReactJS & ExpressJS to Nginx

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx

I have a typical Ubuntu VPS setup (20.04LTS) where I have installed the Nginx Server.
I have two local repos with front-end reactJS code repo and back-end ExpressJS code repo. 
I will start the ExpressJS on the 3000 port with forever start. I have also a mysql db.
I have configured Nginx to server the static files with the root /var/www/[Your repo name]/build; and I can open the html files and it is working. 
The question is, do I need to start on another port for an example the ReactJS npm run start or is Nginx enough? Could you help me out with some links or best practices?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `CRA` (create react app), it ships with a build script, so after running `npm run build` the whole app is built into static files including a `index.html` and some `js` and `css` files. all you need to do is to config `nginx` to serve that `index.html`. so nginx is enough for that. if you're using `react-router` in your app keep in mind that you may need to use `try_files` directive of nginx for serving that `index.html` for any incoming requests.

for more information about react-router and nginx see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43954597/5421321).

If you're doing `SSR` (Server Side Rendering) you need a process manager like `pm2` or `forever` to serve your app internally and `proxy_pass` directive of nginx to reverse proxy incoming requests to your app. [More info](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the intro. I think my developer is using create react app. And I have configureg nginx to server index.html. I am not sure how to check if we are using Server Side Rendering. Where could I check it out?

Comment: if you're using bare CRA you're not doing SSR, a react app with SSR usually is built on top of `nextjs`, `gatsby` or have a custom SSR engine with a `server.js` in root directory.

Comment: Hi. I have found out that we are using react Router , so I did configure before the : server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name _;

# react app & front-end files
location / {
root /home/ubuntu/front-end/html;
try_files $uri /index.html;
}

# node api reverse proxy
location /api/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3030/;
} This should be enough I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I have the files in the public folder with html and index.html. This should be enough for nginx as a start point ? My config.

Comment: please edit your question if you want to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

All the static files like index.html and assets will be served from your "root /var/www/[Your repo name]/build" folder, when the user opens your base url and sent as response for the get call. From your code, make sure to append '/api/' to all your backend requests from ui, so that it will get forwarded to your service running on port 3030.

Comment: Hi. Yes I have appended the code to the /api . This is quite clear. But I am still confused, should I start for ReactJS frontend with npm run star and also for ExpressJS backend with npm run start (and add some proxy). Or this is not needed if I run only react.router without nextjs ( I think I have seen reactdom packages used in frontend). With react npm run start , I see it starts his own development server. What is the best practice in production with this situation and NGINX ?

Comment: It is not necessary to run a dev server on a production environment. Your need to build your project on the production server(either by jenkins or manually login to the server machine), and when the 'dist' folder is created, it have all necessary files to load your UI page. In nginx, always serve the dist folder in the root path, '/' so that your index.html containing the links of app.min.js and app.min.css are served to the browser requesting the page.

Comment: And one more point here is, when you run a dev-server, it exposes your source-maps to the outer world, which may not be a good practice. If you start to serve static bundles, it is handy to move to serverless architecture.

Comment: @VIijay122 - Thanks for the good explanation. Do you have maybe some links on how to build the project of ReactJS and creating the /dist folder and making all of the nginx settings for production. Maybe some tutorial or best practice link with the steps ?

Comment: Sure. Building a react app is done either through webpack, or through scripts to generate the dist folder. Once the dist is generated, from nginx configuration, dist folder is pointed to root url. Kindly refer below link for detailed steps. https://dev.to/xarala221/the-easiest-way-to-deploy-a-react-web-application-2l8a