# react router, nginx, node, static files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, proxy, create-react-app

I know similar questions have been asked but I can't find an answer for the most common node/react/nginx config.

Backend node app I want to reverse proxy to on :port
client is built with create-react-app and built
I want "[deep links](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)" with react-router to work
I want to serve static files with nginx not node

After compiling the client, I move it into `server/build`
and then deploy the whole `server` folder.

So question 1 is if this is the best final structure for deployment?
The reason I like this is that the built files are cleanly in a `build` directory, and not munged up in `public` with other server side files such as images so can be replaced on next build easily.

So the server looks something like this:

```
/mnt/ext250/web-apps/cbg.rik.ai/
├── build
│   └── index.html
│   └── static
│       ├── css
│       ├── js
│       └── media

// files that were in server/public

├── public
│   └── images
│       ├── items
│       ├── logo
│       └── rooms

server.js
```

So I pm2 start up the `server.js`
App works fine directly on :port:
App works fine at the root eg domain.com and I can use client links.
But when I directly load a "deep link" the server times out.

So the question is how to configure the `index` to be served for deep links
and still keep API routes working to the node backend.

Do I need to have clear different routes, eg:

```
  # declare API routes first
  location /api {
    try_files $uri @backend ;
  }

  # then everything else?
  location / {
    try_files $uri build/index.html;
  }
```

When I do set this it seems the main site gets served as the wrong mimetype or something...:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.dd03fa6d.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
cbg.rik.ai/:1 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://cbg.rik.ai/static/css/main.573d8e92.chunk.css".
```

Full config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name cbg.rik.ai;
  root /mnt/ext250/web-apps/cbg.rik.ai;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/cbg.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/cbg.error.log;

  index index.html;

  # for other browser deep link routes serve the index file
  location / {
    try_files $uri build/index.html @backend;
  }

  # proxy to node app @backend
  location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:33010;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Following is necessary for Websocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  # certbot stuff
}
```

related:
[React-router and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx)

try_files documentation
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#trying-several-options

Comment: It's trying to load a stylesheet but `try_files` doesn't find the `$uri`, probably because it's actually inside the `build` directory, so it sends back the contents of index.html. Try adding `build/` to the `root`.

Comment: the problem is that i have some other static files too eg an `/images` directory.

Answer (score 2):

OK the problem for me after much hair pulling was that some source static files had the wrong permissions. This may save someone else some time.

I use a `Makefile` for these tasks and added a `fixPermissions` task. The Makefile is nice to handle dependent tasks so I can have:

```
clean:
    rm -rf client/build
    rm -rf server/build

# image files can have wrong permissions when copied from internet
fixPermissions:
    # directories 755
    find server/cdn -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
    # files 644
    find server/cdn -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

build: clean fixPermissions
    cd client && npm run build

move:
    mv client/build server

prep: clean build move


sync:
    rsync -avi --delete \
        server/ ${login}:${deploydir}

    echo "done"

deploy: prep sync pm2restart
```

Then deploy is just `make deploy` and even with filename completion with zsh. Old Skool but it works!

final nginx config:

```
# cbg.rik.ai
# port: 33010

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name cbg.rik.ai;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/cbg.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/cbg.error.log;
  root /mnt/ext250/web-apps/cbg.rik.ai/build;

  # static files from server/cdn
  # make sure files are 644
  # better to use alias than have two roots
  location /cdn/ {
    alias /mnt/ext250/web-apps/cbg.rik.ai/cdn/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ default.png;
  }

  # for other browser deep link routes serve the index file
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  # proxy to node app @backend
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:33010;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Following is necessary for Websocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  # followed by certbot stuff

}
```

I'm not quite sure if the ordering of the locations has impact. Anyway a few hours wasted on this stuff so hopefully helps someone else. Or probably later me :0