# Modifying nginx.conf for Azure App Linux Service

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying a ReactJS application in Azure App Service that runs on Linux container. The ReactJS application has router. The refresh of internal pages failing due to the ReactJS routing. As per [React-router and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx) , I can solve this problem by adding following block in nginx.conf

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Now my problem is that how can I modify the nginx.conf inside the Azure App Linux container? I tried to copy to /home/site. It did not work. It always taking nginx.conf from /etc/nginx. If I replace that /etc/nginx/nginx.conf with my own version, it will be overwritten on next reboot.

Is there anyway I can use my own nginx.conf? or should I create a custom container to solve it?

Comment: did you solved It? I'm thinking about switching to Windows hosting

Answer (score 11):

You can actually modify your nginx configuration via the startup command of your app service.

- SSH into your app service.
- Copy over the default nginx configuration file to your home directory:

  ```
  cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /home/site/nginx.conf
  ```
- Modify the copied over nginx configuration file `/home/site/nginx.conf` and include your custom configuration.

  ```
  vi /home/site/nginx.conf
  ```
- Create a bash file `/home/site/startup.sh` with the following contents:

  ```
  cp /home/site/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
  service nginx reload
  ```
- Set your app service startup command to `/home/site/startup.sh`.

During startup your app service will overwrite the default nginx configuration and reload the nginx service. It's not the most maintainable solution but it works.

Comment: This seems a horrible hack, its like Microsoft forgot to add a feature to allow users to extend nginx, e.g. by including a file in /home/conf by default.

Comment: @mvdgun works for me, thx for share it

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify the nginx.conf. Since you're inside a Microsoft docker container, you will not be able to change that.

Any files or directories outside of the /home directory, will not be persisted between site recycles. This can impact you in a couple of different ways. You don't have access to change that since it is locked down under the Azure sandbox.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#CIFS

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient, but I did find an answer to this:

Essentially:

- Make a copy of the nginx config file and save it in your /home dir
- Make the edits you need
- Use a Startup Command (Configuration > General Settings > Startup Command) to copy the nginx config back to the nginx directory and restart nginx.

This works great with GitHub Actions deployment btw, so it's a pretty solid solution.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/configure-nginx-for-php-8-linux-azure-app-service/ba-p/3069373

Answer (score 0):

Need to use Startup command in Azure Web App settings/configuration

```
sleep 300
cp /home/site/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

Please refer this: https://www.michev.info/blog/post/5329/wordpress-on-linux-app-service-in-azure-and-nginx-conf-troubles
I hope Microsoft fix this problem.