# React-router URL's, Routing node/express & file structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

### File structure

```
.root
|-client
| -build
| -node_modules
| -public
| -src
|  -components
|  -resources
|   -data
|   -images
|   -templates
|-server
| -models
| -public
| -routes
| -server.js
```

### server.js

```
//Required NPM Packages
const express                =         require('express'),
      app                    =         express(),
      cors                   =         require('cors'),
      bodyParser             =         require('body-parser'),
      mongoose               =         require('mongoose'),
      methodOverride         =         require('method-override');

//MongoDB models.
const Product                =         require('./models/Product');

//Routes.
const indexRoute             =         require('./routes/index');
const demoRoute              =         require('./routes/demo');
const bootstrapTemplateRoute =         require('./routes/bootstrapTemplate');

//Port.
const _PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Connect to mongoDB.
mongoose.connect({pathToMongoDB}, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true});

//Setup body-parser.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

//Allow express/node to accept Cross-origin resource sharing.
app.use(cors());

//Set view engine to EJS.
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Change views to specified directory
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client','src','Resources','templates'));


app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"))
app.use(express.static("client/build"));
app.use(express.static("client/Resources/templates"));


//Setup method override.
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

//register routes to express.
app.use('/', indexRoute);
app.use('/demo', demoRoute);
app.use('/bootstrapTemplate', bootstrapTemplateRoute)

//listen to established port.
app.listen(_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`The server has started on port ${_PORT}!`);
});


module.exports = app;
```

### Question

When I click the back button or load the page in my browser bar nodeJS states that it cannot get the page. I recognise that the front-end and back-end request are different as the React-Router takes care of routing via it's own javaScript allowing for zero page reloads, but how do you actually solve the problem on nodeJS/Express?

Also when I go to localhost:3000/demo it returns the data from my mongoDB and renders it in json format rather then loading the correct page.

Currently working on a MERN Stack with the below Nginx basic routing config.

```
http{

    server{
        listen 3000;
        root pathToRoot/client/build;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }
            
    }
}

events {

}
```

I believe the problem is within my routing via express/nodejs. I can't create express specific routes and render the correct page because react is rendering it for me. I looked at the following question [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually). Should I just do a catch-all and re-route back to the main index page? This seems like it would render bookmarks unusable.

## Edit

Here are the 2 node routes.

### index.js

```
const express                = require('express'),
      router                 = express.Router();


router.get("/", (req,res) => {
    //Render index page.
    res.render("index");
});
```

### demo.js

```
 const express = require('express'),
      router = express.Router();

const Product = require('../models/Product');


router.get('/:searchInput', (req,res) => {
      Product.find({ $text: {$search: req.params.searchInput}}, (err,foundItem) => {
            if(err){
                  console.log(err);
            }else{
                  res.send(foundItem);
            }            
      })
})

router.get('/', (req, res) => {     
      Product.find({}, (err, foundItem) => {
            res.send(foundItem);
      });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: [Does this work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx)? I think the issue is that you are only serving the `index.html` file for the `/` route, but you want to serve it for all routes.

Comment: I added an edit with the two routes that I currently have. I'm currently only serving the index.html file when we land on the page. Although I'm confused that I would need to render more than one page as React renders all the front-end pages. When I route to the demo page the call is made to mongo and I get the data back. As per React useEffect/useState

Comment: I might be way off but generally the servers are set up to return index.html instead of a 404 page. That way, you can ask the server for any ol' route and if it doesn't know, it returns the React page and it React-Router DOM figures it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would try separate out your development folders from your build folders as it can get a bit messy once you start running `react build`. A structure I use is:

```
api  build  frontend  run_build.sh
```

The `api` folder contains my development for express server, the `frontend` contains my development for react and the `build` is created from the `run_build.sh` script, it looks something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf build/

# Build the front end
cd frontend
npm run build

# Copy the API files
cd ..
rsync -av --progress api/ build/ --exclude node_modules

# Copy the front end build code
cp -a frontend/build/. build/client/

# Install dependencies
cd build
npm install

# Start the server
npm start
```

Now in your `build` directory you should have subfolder `client` which contains the built version of your react code without any clutter. To tell express to use certain routes for react, in the express `server.js` file add the following.

**NOTE** add your express api routes first before adding the react routes or it will not work.

```
// API Routing files - Located in the routes directory // 
var indexRouter         = require('./routes/index')
var usersRouter         = require('./routes/users');
var oAuthRouter         = require('./routes/oauth');
var loginVerification   = require('./routes/login_verification')

// API Routes //
app.use('/',indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/oauth',oAuthRouter);
app.use('/login_verification',loginVerification);

// React routes - Located in the client directory // 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client'))); // Serve react files
app.use('/login',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))
app.use('/welcome',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))
```

The react `App` function in the `App.js` component file will look like the following defining the routes you have just added told express to use for react.

```
function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
     <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" render={(props)=><Login/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/welcome" render={(props)=><Welcome/>}/>
      </Switch>
     </div>
   </Router> 
  );
}
```

Under the components folder there are components for `login` and `welcome`. Now navigating to `http://MyWebsite/login` will prompt express to use the react routes, while for example navigating to `http://MyWebsite/login_verification` will use the express API routes.